# SQL Query involving Cross Join Issue(prints too many records than expected)

Tags: sql

When I manually insert each select command into DB2 it prints everything correct:
[image]

But when I use the code below which makes all 5 tables 1 huge table it prints out too many records:
[image]

Code:

```
SELECT A.PERF_NO, B.A_NAME, C.TCOMP_NAME, D.P_TITLE, E.PDATE from (select PERF_NO from PERFORMS) A \
CROSS JOIN (select A_NAME from ACTOR_BORN_LIVES s, PERFORMS z where s.A_NO=z.PERF_NO) B \
CROSS JOIN (select TCOMP_NAME from THEATER_COMP_PLACE s, PERFORMS z where s.TCOMP_NO=z.TCOMP_NO) C \
CROSS JOIN (select P_TITLE from PLAY s, PERFORMS z where s.P_NO=z.PLAY_NO) D \
CROSS JOIN (select PDATE from PERFORMS s, PLAY z where z.P_NO=s.PLAY_NO) E
```

**Any idea about this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` joins every row from first result set to every row from second result set. This means that if you are joining 5 records from one result with 6 results from the second result set you get 5x6=30 results. What you actually need is `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT perf.PERF_NO, born.A_NAME, theat.TCOMP_NAME, pl.P_TITLE, pl.PDATE 
FROM PERFORMS perf INNER JOIN ACTOR_BORN_LIVES born ON born.A_NO=perf.PERF_NO
    INNER JOIN THEATER_COMP_PLACE theat ON theat.TCOMP_NO=perf.TCOMP_NO
    INNER JOIN PLAY pl ON pl.P_NO=perf.PLAY_NO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about  inner join until now.

Comment: Also, when would outer join be useful?